# The condition of linear operation of the transistor Dipole in small signal mode

Tags: transistors, mosfet, bjt, aviation-electronics

How small should the base-emitter voltage changes of the transistor be so that the relationship between the base-emitter voltage changes and the collector current changes can be considered linear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a BJT, the voltage scale is the [thermal voltage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boltzmann_constant#The_thermal_voltage), about 26 mV at room temperature. The base voltage change must be substantially smaller than that to approach linearity.